# The specified value for groupName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write IAM policy by Cloudformation.
I try to deploy by below yaml file.
It can't build and get error.

However, Groupname looks like not have any these characters.(+=,.@_-)
Do you know how to resolve it?

**Error**
The specified value for groupName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_- (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: id; Proxy: null)

````
Description: ""

Metadata:
  Generator: former2

Resources:
  MyIAMPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: TestLogPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:test_api-app-test:*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:test_api-app-test:*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateExportTask
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:test_api-app-test:*"
      Groups:
        - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:group/createCloudFormationTest"```
````

Comment: Is that the whole template?

Comment: No, it's not the whole template.
Other resources work. But, MyIAMPolicy only doesn't work.
Then, I tried to write minimum template.

Comment: It should be  the name of the group, not the ARN.

Comment: Oh, it seems like work! I try to write the whole template again.
If I get other error, I will write it again:)

Comment: I've written an answer below; if the problem has been resolved upvote it/accept it

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-groups):

> **Groups**
>
> The name of the group to associate the policy with.

so you should specify the name of the group, not its ARN.